# Cassandra nodetool in standalone mode

Tags: cassandra

I've got Cassandra 0.7 running in standalone mode and I'm tryin to run nodetool but I'm getting JMX exceptions. Isn't the JMX configuration required on accessing a remote server? I'm accessing my local machine.

Also why is nodetool looking for 63.251.179.13?

```
    [rav@ubix bin]$ ./nodetool -h 127.0.0.1 flush
Error connection to remote JMX agent!
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 63.251.179.13; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:128)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2343)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:296)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:267)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.connect(NodeProbe.java:144)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeProbe.<init>(NodeProbe.java:114)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeCmd.main(NodeCmd.java:621)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:495)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:206)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 10 more
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try nodetool with -h or --host and -p or --port as per the instructions:

```
 -h,--host <arg>        node hostname or ip address
 -p,--port <arg>        remote jmx agent port number
```

When Cassandra is offline, check the ports in use to see if another process is using the default port that Cassandra binds to.  You can find the default in `conf/cassandra-env.sh`

Once you know the port, you can see if another process is bound to it with `netstat -an`

If nothing is running on the port, and you start up cassandra, verify that it is running on the correct port and try to connect again with the -p or --port arguments.  More information can be found here:  http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted

Is the machine unix or windows?  do you have a bad entry in `/etc/hosts` indicating that 127.0.0.1 maps to another hostname or IP address, namely 63.251.179.13

Comment: I second the /etc/hosts suggestion.  I've found that Cassandra is picky with having /etc/hosts set correctly, so make sure that you have localhost resolving to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running nodetool on an instance of Cassandra running locally on my machine. When trying to run `nodetool -h 127.0.0.1` nodetool was issuing an exception relating to JMX that looked like this (where there was an unknown - to me - IP Address).

```
Error connecting to remote JMX agent!
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: ; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Host is down
```

[Douglas Muth posted a similar issue here, and from this](http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/125vaf74fv/nodetool-talking-to-an-old-ip-address-and-timing-out#20120529zbfesdr0p7ety2arq20y6bd6w4), I found out that Cassandra seems to be recording the hostname at startup. Unfortunately, by the time I ran nodetool the hostname had  become stale (my IP address is allocated dynamically).

My solution then, was to restart cassandra, which updated the IP and rerun nodetool. No more JMX errors, no more strange IP address. This worked a treat for me as I'm running a local instance of Cassandra on localhost and don't mind the restart but it's not a very satisfactory solution.